# Plot Elliptical arc in d3.js between three points

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to drawn in elliptical arc in D3.js using three points?. I wish to draw an elliptical arc between three points. I know the traditional method of making use of source and target location to plot the arc. How can I achieve this for three points in D3.js

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by making use of a 'LineString' specified in GeoJSON format. You can add as many points as you would like to make the line follow a path. It will be drawn and read by javascript as an arc itself

```
  links.push({
            type: "LineString",
            coordinates: [
                [ co-ordinate1, co-ordinate1 ],
                [co-ordinate2, co-ordinate2,
                [ co-ordinate3, co-ordinate3]
            ]
        })
  }
```